# How can I clean reports?

Tags: civireport

Which is the procedure /command to cleaning (deleting the records) of any report?
I have tried with "delete", but it seems to delete the form.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot take any action on a report other than:

1. add to group
2. export as CSV
3. print

If you want to take action on contacts, you would do so by

1. search (find contacts, find contributions, etc)
2. use the 'actions' menu, choose 'delete'